# How to go through a pandas data frame and only keep rows that have the same value throughout the entire row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
 NaN NaN NaN  2   2   2
 NaN NaN NaN  2   7   9
  1  NaN NaN  2   6   4
  8  NaN NaN  7   6   9
  1  NaN NaN  1   1   1
 NaN NaN NaN  2   7   9
  2  NaN NaN  2   2   2
  8  NaN NaN  7   6   9
  1  NaN NaN  1  NaN  1
```

How do I only keep rows where all of the values are equal to each other? Such that I get a pandas data frame like this:

```
 NaN NaN NaN  2   2   2
  1  NaN NaN  1   1   1
  2  NaN NaN  2   2   2
  1  NaN NaN  1  NaN  1
```

Comment: let's not bring bias into the equation here, although it is considered proper to _accept_ a solution if it meets your needs. with this question in mind, would you please share your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataFrame.nunique` will not count `NaN` so it suffices to check if there is a single unique value row-wise

```
df.loc[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1)]

     0   1   2  3    4  5
0  NaN NaN NaN  2  2.0  2
4  1.0 NaN NaN  1  1.0  1
6  2.0 NaN NaN  2  2.0  2
8  1.0 NaN NaN  1  NaN  1
```

Comment: you can save 4 characters with `df[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1)]`

Comment: Could even remove the `axis` `df[df.nunique(1).eq(1)]` though I'm not a fan of how easy it might be to confuse the meaning of  `1` for those two different methods.

Comment: Yeah, I've been leaving `axis=n` arguments in more often.

Answer (score 2):

For a numpy based approach we could use [`partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) here to check for a *valid* value in each row, and compare it against the the other columns:

```
import numpy as np

a = df.values
a.partition(0)
m = a[:,0,None] == a[:,1:]
m = np.concatenate([np.full((a.shape[0],1), True), m], axis=1)
m[np.isnan(a)] = True
out = df[m.all(1)]
```

---

```
print(out)

0  NaN NaN NaN  2  2.0  2
4  1.0 NaN NaN  1  1.0  1
6  2.0 NaN NaN  2  2.0  2
8  1.0 NaN NaN  1  NaN  1
```